# How to use wpLink without editor?

Tags: links, editor

I would like to create theme option to add a link. 
Loading these scripts and triggering the dialog works fine if wp editor is present.

```
wp_enqueue_script('wplink');
wp_enqueue_script('wpdialogs');
wp_enqueue_script('wpdialogs-popup');
wp_enqueue_style('wp-jquery-ui-dialog');
wp_enqueue_style('thickbox');

wp_editor('', 'unique_id', array('editor_class'=>'hidden'));



$('.add-link').on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

      wpLink.open();
      return false;
});
```

but how to make it open link dialog box without editor being present?

This is what I am after

[image] 
[image]

Comment: It's all tied pretty tightly to the editor, the link dialog is built by a method of the editor class, and the script that invokes it needs an editor instance.

Comment: what do u mean without the editor? where do u want to have it?

Comment: @Trix in theme settings

Comment: You're better off building your own or using something like Advanced Custom Field's relationship field: http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/relationship/ or Custom Field Suite's relationship field: http://docs.customfieldsuite.com/field-types/relationship.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is not ethical way of doing this. But still there is a way to do this. WordPress wrote wpLink script keeping in mind that editor is there but still WordPress handle when editor is not there **(Good Thing)**

Consider this example and assume that we are using it on front-end in footer.

First enqueue the essential style and scripts.

```
function enqueue_scripts_209490() {
    wp_enqueue_script('wplink');
    wp_enqueue_style( 'editor-buttons' );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_scripts_209490');
```

Now hook this function in footer **Read the inline comments**

```
function display_wplink_html_209490() {
    //Our textarea, click to open the link edior and insert the link in same editor
    echo '<textarea id="example_209490"></textarea>';

    // Require the core editor class so we can call wp_link_dialog function to print the HTML.
    // Luckly it is public static method ;)
    require_once ABSPATH . "wp-includes/class-wp-editor.php";
    _WP_Editors::wp_link_dialog(); ?>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        /* We need ajaxurl to send ajax to retrive links */
        var ajaxurl = "<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php'); ?>";
        jQuery(document).ready(function (){
            jQuery('#example_209490').click(function (){
                wpLink.open('example_209490'); /* Bind to open link editor! */
            });
        })
    </script><?php
}
add_action('wp_footer', 'display_wplink_html_209490');
```

> **Note:** It will not work when user is not logged-in because of js error 
>   `setUserSetting` is not defined and no AJAX response when user not 
>   logged-in.

Comment: Somehow I had this all working earlier without the `_WP_Editors` code, and it broke.  Your answer saved the day - thank you!