# How to add "Insert/Edit link" button in custom popup tinymce window?

Tags: tinymce, buttons, quicktag

I need to insert some text in the body of the article, that turns into a "side-tag" by wrapping it inside some div tags with custom classes.

I've created a custom button in tinymce that pops up a new window with a text field. You write the text and when you hit OK it adds the beginning and endig div tags and inserts it into the wp editor where your cursor was.

Here is the code:

```
(function () {
    tinymce.PluginManager.add('custom_mce_button2', function(editor, url) {
        editor.addButton('custom_mce_button2', {
            icon: false,
            text: 'Side Tag',
            onclick: function (e) {
                editor.windowManager.open( {
                    title: 'Insert a Sidetag',
                    body: [{
                        type: 'textbox',
                        name: 'title',
                        placeholder: 'Type the side tag content here.',
                        multiline: true,
                        minWidth: 700,
                        minHeight: 50,
                    },
                    {
                        type: 'button',
                        name: 'link',
                        text: 'Insert/Edit link',
                        onclick: function( e ) {
                            //get the Wordpess' "Insert/edit link" popup window.
                        },
                    }],
                    onsubmit: function( e ) {
                        editor.insertContent( '<div class="side-tag-wrap hidden-xs"><div class="side-tag">' + e.data.title + '</div></div>');
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
})();
```

And what it does:

[image]

So far everything works but...
I also want to be able to add links while the popup window is still on, exactly how the "Insert/Edit link" button of the default editor works. I know how to use the link plugin of tinymce but this doesn't help. I mainly want to link posts that are already published so I need this:

[image]

Is there a way to call this button in my custom popup window or call the quicktags function ?

Comment: I think this will help you get started http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/209490/how-to-use-wplink-without-editor

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So I'm answering my own question, for those that face or will face the same problem.

I have added two buttons. One opens wordpress' build-in window to select a post and inserts the link. The other opens wordpress' build-in media window to select an image. That is what somehow what you get at the end.

[image]

You will need two PHP functions and one JS one in a separate file.
In the functions.php, or where ever you have your custom functions add the following:

```
/**
 * Add a custom button to tinymce editor
 */
function custom_mce_buttons() {
    // Check if WYSIWYG is enabled
    if ( get_user_option( 'rich_editing' ) == 'true' ) {
        add_filter( 'mce_external_plugins', 'custom_tinymce_plugin' );
        add_filter( 'mce_buttons', 'register_mce_buttons' );
    }
}
add_action('admin_head', 'custom_mce_buttons');


// Add the path to the js file with the custom button function
function custom_tinymce_plugin( $plugin_array ) {
    $plugin_array['custom_mce_button1'] = get_template_directory_uri() .'PATH_TO_THE_JS_FILE';
    $plugin_array['custom_mce_button2'] = get_template_directory_uri() .'PATH_TO_THE_OTHER_JS_FILE';
    return $plugin_array;
}

// Register and add new button in the editor
function register_mce_buttons( $buttons ) {
    array_push( $buttons, 'custom_mce_button1' );
    array_push( $buttons, 'custom_mce_button2' );
    return $buttons;
}
```

And the JS file.

```
(function () {
    tinymce.PluginManager.add('custom_mce_button1', function(editor, url) {
        editor.addButton('custom_mce_button1', {
            icon: false,
            text: 'THE_TEXT_OF_THE_BUTTON',
            onclick: function (e) {
                editor.windowManager.open( {
                    title: 'THE_TITLE_OF_THE_POPUP_WINDOW',
                    body: [{
                        type: 'textbox',
                        name: 'title',
                        placeholder: 'PLACE_HOLDER_TEXT',
                        multiline: true,
                        minWidth: 700,
                        minHeight: 50,
                    },
                    {
                        type: 'button',
                        name: 'link',
                        text: 'Insert/Edit link',
                        onclick: function( e ) {
                            //get the Wordpess' "Insert/edit link" popup window.
                            var textareaId = jQuery('.mce-custom-textarea').attr('id');
                            wpActiveEditor = true; //we need to override this var as the link dialogue is expecting an actual wp_editor instance
                            wpLink.open( textareaId ); //open the link popup
                            return false;
                        },
                    },
                    {
                        type: 'button',
                        name: 'image',
                        classes: 'sidetag-media-button',
                        text: 'Insert Media',
                        onclick: function( e ) {

                            jQuery(function($){
                                // Set all variables to be used in scope
                                var frame;
                                //it has to match the "textareaID" above, because it is the input field that we are
                                //going to insert the data in HTML format.
                                var imgContainer = $( '.mce-custom-textarea' );

                                // ADD IMAGE LINK
                                event.preventDefault();

                                // If the media frame already exists, reopen it.
                                if ( frame ) {
                                    frame.open();
                                    return;
                                }

                                // Create a new media frame
                                frame = wp.media({
                                    title: 'Select or Upload Media',
                                    button: {
                                      text: 'Use this media'
                                    },
                                    multiple: false  // Set to true to allow multiple files to be selected
                                });

                                // When an image is selected in the media frame...
                                frame.on( 'select', function() {

                                    // Get media attachment details from the frame state
                                    var attachment = frame.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();

                                    // Send the attachment URL to our custom image input field.
                                    var imageContent = '<img class="side-tag-image" src="'+attachment.url+'" alt="'+attachment.alt+'" style="max-width:100%;"/>'+attachment.caption;
                                    imgContainer.val( imageContent + imgContainer.val() );

                                });
                                // Finally, open the modal on click
                                frame.open();
                        });
                        return false;
                        }
                    }],
                    onsubmit: function( e ) {
                        // wrap it with a div and give it a class name
                        editor.insertContent( '<div class="CLASS_NAME">' + e.data.title + '</div>');
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
})();
```

I hope this will help some of you..

Comment: I got two issues with this: the insert media popup opens up behind my other popup; and the link is not output at all.